# TypeScript cant use array prototype

Tags: arrays, typescript

After looking at other stack overflow answers, I could not fix my error.
I've tried the following

[A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39877156/how-to-extend-string-prototype-and-use-it-next-in-typescript)
[B](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47591724/typescript-extend-array-prototype)

Here is my TS

```
interface Array<T> {
  asyncForEach(callback: CallableFunction): void;
}

Array.prototype.asyncForEach = async function (callback: CallableFunction) {
  // this represents our array
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    // We call the callback for each entry
    await callback(this[index], index, this);
  }
};

(async () => {
  const buttons: string[] = [things.methButtonId, things.cashButtonId];

  buttons.asyncForEach(async (button) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      //do something
    }
  })
});
```

I get the following error on build:

> src/index.ts:13:17 - error TS2339: Property 'asyncForEach' does not exist on type 'any[]'.
>
> 13 Array.prototype.asyncForEach = async function (callback: CallableFunction) {
>
> src/index.ts:39:11 - error TS2339: Property 'asyncForEach' does not exist on type 'string[]'.
>
> 39   buttons.asyncForEach(async (button) => {

Visual code gives me the following error:

> Property 'asyncForEach' does not exist on type 'any[]'.ts(2339)

Here is my config file.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    // "incremental": true,                   /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "target": "es2020",                          /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017', 'ES2018', 'ES2019', 'ES2020', or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "commonjs",                     /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', 'es2020', or 'ESNext'. */
    // "lib": [],                             /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    // "allowJs": true,                       /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    // "checkJs": true,                       /* Report errors in .js files. */
    // "jsx": "preserve",                     /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    // "declaration": true,                   /* Generates corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "declarationMap": true,                /* Generates a sourcemap for each corresponding '.d.ts' file. */
    // "sourceMap": true,                     /* Generates corresponding '.map' file. */
    // "outFile": "./",                       /* Concatenate and emit output to single file. */
    "outDir": "./dist",                        /* Redirect output structure to the directory. */
    // "rootDir": "./",                       /* Specify the root directory of input files. Use to control the output directory structure with --outDir. */
    // "composite": true,                     /* Enable project compilation */
    // "tsBuildInfoFile": "./",               /* Specify file to store incremental compilation information */
    // "removeComments": true,                /* Do not emit comments to output. */
    // "noEmit": true,                        /* Do not emit outputs. */
    // "importHelpers": true,                 /* Import emit helpers from 'tslib'. */
    // "downlevelIteration": true,            /* Provide full support for iterables in 'for-of', spread, and destructuring when targeting 'ES5' or 'ES3'. */
    // "isolatedModules": true,               /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */
    "noImplicitAny": false,                 /* Raise error on expressions and declarations with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "strictNullChecks": true,              /* Enable strict null checks. */
    // "strictFunctionTypes": true,           /* Enable strict checking of function types. */
    // "strictBindCallApply": true,           /* Enable strict 'bind', 'call', and 'apply' methods on functions. */
    "strictPropertyInitialization": true,  /* Enable strict checking of property initialization in classes. */
    // "noImplicitThis": true,                /* Raise error on 'this' expressions with an implied 'any' type. */
    // "alwaysStrict": true,                  /* Parse in strict mode and emit "use strict" for each source file. */

    /* Additional Checks */
    // "noUnusedLocals": true,                /* Report errors on unused locals. */
    // "noUnusedParameters": true,            /* Report errors on unused parameters. */
    // "noImplicitReturns": true,             /* Report error when not all code paths in function return a value. */
    // "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,    /* Report errors for fallthrough cases in switch statement. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    // "moduleResolution": "node",            /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
    // "baseUrl": "./",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
    // "paths": {},                           /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
    // "rootDirs": [],                        /* List of root folders whose combined content represents the structure of the project at runtime. */
    // "typeRoots": [],                       /* List of folders to include type definitions from. */
    // "types": [],                           /* Type declaration files to be included in compilation. */
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,  /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true,                  /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */
    // "preserveSymlinks": true,              /* Do not resolve the real path of symlinks. */
    // "allowUmdGlobalAccess": true,          /* Allow accessing UMD globals from modules. */

    /* Source Map Options */
    // "sourceRoot": "",                      /* Specify the location where debugger should locate TypeScript files instead of source locations. */
    // "mapRoot": "",                         /* Specify the location where debugger should locate map files instead of generated locations. */
    // "inlineSourceMap": true,               /* Emit a single file with source maps instead of having a separate file. */
    // "inlineSources": true,                 /* Emit the source alongside the sourcemaps within a single file; requires '--inlineSourceMap' or '--sourceMap' to be set. */

    /* Experimental Options */
    // "experimentalDecorators": true,        /* Enables experimental support for ES7 decorators. */
    // "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,         /* Enables experimental support for emitting type metadata for decorators. */
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    /* Advanced Options */
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true  /* Disallow inconsistently-cased references to the same file. */
  }, "include": ["./src/*.ts", "src/index.js"]
}
```

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Did you try wrapping the `interface` in a `declare global { }` block? If you are in a module context, TypeScript will otherwise think that you are creating a local interface called `Array<T>` in your module.

Comment: You are amazing! I tried the this but in a seperate .d.ts file and it didn't work, but putting it in my index.ts file worked!

Answer (score 0):

@CherryDT's comment works!

My Working TS :

```
declare global {
  interface Array<T> {
    asyncForEach(callback: CallableFunction);
  }
}


Array.prototype.asyncForEach = async function (callback: CallableFunction) {
  // this represents our array
  for (let index = 0; index < this.length; index++) {
    // We call the callback for each entry
    await callback(this[index], index, this);
  }
};
```